# Android Actionbar Tabs not displaying text when setting an icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to set an icon and text to a tab from my `ActionBar`.

```
ActionBar.Tab artistTab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.untitled).setText("Artists");
```

I set both, text and icon but when I start the app it'll only display an icon. Only if I leave the `setIcon()` function it'll display text.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do changes in main.xml file.

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```